# T-SQL Create Customized Column with Trigger or Function

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers, sql-function

I am working on a database column, I'm deciding between trigger and function I believe 1 of these is what I will need because I don’t think stored procedure can be run after an insert. I'm open to any suggestions though, I have a column that will need a string value then the current year of 2 digits followed by a – and a counter after. On the start of a new year I will need the counter to restart at 
001. How should I do this?

EX. VSP20-001, VSP20-002 … and the next year, VSP21-001, VSP21-002 …

Here is the start of my trigger. I know it needs a lot more. I’m not sure if I should do it as a computed column or if I can do it all In just 1 column.

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_ProposalTest
ON dbo.Serv_Quotes
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @yearTst nvarchar(10);
    SET @yearTst = (SELECT FORMAT(GETDATE(), 'yy'))

    DECLARE @word nvarchar(5);
    SET @word = 'VSP';

    DECLARE @counter int;
    SET @counter = RIGHT(@fullvar,3) + 1; -- still need to create this
```

Comment: First thing you'll need to know is that you will need it to be a **BEFORE** INSERT trigger. The second thing to consider is you can be dealing with multiple inserted rows at once, and need to determine which one should get `VSPYY-(N)` and which should get `VSPYY-(N+1)`.

Comment: @Uueerdo SQL Server does not have **BEFORE** triggers. So that's right out. It can be done with either type of trigger (instead of vs. after) that sql server supports.

Comment: And what happens when a row is deleted?

Comment: Current year of 2 digits? 20 years after Y2K we should all refuse to do this.

Comment: @SMor I stand corrected on that; most my trigger work has been in MySQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an alternate approach, you could get this all done with a default value on the column that uses a [`SEQUENCE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-sequence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) object. (Unfortunately, you can't use a sequence in a computed column. Can't explain that distinction.)

You could create a simple sequence for your final value, then just concatenate the rest of the values together in the definition of the default value.

In order to cycle it for your annual reset, create a SQL Agent job (or whatever your scheduling tool is) to run an `ALTER` statement to reset the sequence.

```
create sequence dbo.ProjID
AS INTEGER
START WITH 10
INCREMENT BY 1;

GO

create table testseq (
    ID bigint identity(1,1) not null,
    val int,
    testVal nvarchar(10) default ( CONCAT( 'VSP', YEAR( GETDATE() ) % 100 , '-', 
                                   RIGHT( CONCAT('000', NEXT VALUE FOR dbo.ProjID), 3)))
);

GO

insert testseq (val) values (1), (2);

select * from testseq;
```

Results:

```
+----+-----+-----------+
| ID | val |  testVal  |
+----+-----+-----------+
|  1 |   1 | VSP20-010 |
|  2 |   2 | VSP20-011 |
+----+-----+-----------+
```

Then, on January 1st every year:

```
ALTER SEQUENCE dbo.ProjID
  RESTART;
```

Play around with it here and see what you think.

[Rextester Demo](https://rextester.com/BAVW14224).

Comment: Thank you! I am trying to wrap my head around this fully I might have some questions but ill start with this and try a sequence. what is the 'val' column for? and so the sequence keeps track of the current counter value? thats how it can be restarted.

Comment: The testVal column is all that really matters here. The 'val' column was just so I'd have a column to insert data into, in order to demonstrate how the sequence object would increment the column you're actually interested in. The ID column? Utterly useless, all said and done. :)

Comment: To SMor's point, if you can get the powers that be to go with a four digit year, that would be a pretty smart move, too.

Comment: My last question is with default will the data automatically use this sequence even if I insert data through EF C#. each time a row is inserted itll use this sequence and I dont have to do anything special for it. the department wants it to be a 2 digit year so gotta go with what they want. Im just building the program to automate their job.

Comment: This is using the same logic that goes into a table with an `InsertDate` column defaulted to GETDATE(). Don't list the column at all in the `INSERT` statement, and the default value will get populated. So, yeah, it could get overwritten, and that's a risk, but it would be a risk using a trigger, too. As far as EF vs SSIS vs doing it by hand, the table won't care where the insert comes from. It'll just use the default value for the column. Nothing special.

Comment: When I run the default query on my row this is what it gives me. '(concat('VSP',datepart(year,getdate())%(100),'-',right(concat('000',NEXT VALUE FOR [dbo].[seq_proposalTest]),(3))))' and when i go to add a record nothing happens. this is the query - ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Serv_Quotes]
ADD CONSTRAINT def_FUD
DEFAULT CONCAT( 'VSP', YEAR(GETDATE()) % 100, '-', RIGHT( CONCAT('000', NEXT VALUE FOR dbo.seq_proposalTest), 3)) FOR FollowUpDates

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209187/discussion-between-eric-brandt-and-bigbear).

Comment: IT WORKED!!!!! THANK YOU I had to change a property in my EF and it worked with the DEFAULT value you created. Entity Framework Model - StoreGeneratedPattern = Computed.

Comment: That's awesome! Now remember to set up the restart job for the sequence!

Comment: Yes, I created that and tested it out. so perfect and easy to do. Thank you!